# Linking a label syntax?

Tags: c#, hyperlink, label

How would I link a label or do I have to use something different then a label. Such a simple task but im new to Csharp.

Dafault.aspx page

Myspace Link:

```
<a href="<asp:MyspaceLink</asp>">
<asp:Label ID="MyspaceLink" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></a> </p>
<p>
```

FaceBook Link:

```
<a href="<asp:FacebookLink</asp>">
<asp:Label ID="FacebookLink" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label></a> </p>
```

Dafault.aspx.cs

```
foreach (DataRow row in DAMemberInfo.Rows)
{
    MyspaceLink.Text = row["MemberMyspace"].ToString();
    FacebookLink.Text = row["MemberFacebook"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: If you only need the hyperlink like the others say use a hyperlink control; if you need some server side processing the LinkButton control would be your best bet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [Hyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx) control, not a label like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hyperlinkFacebook" 
               NavigateUrl="http://www.facebook.com"
               Text="Facebook"
               Target="_new"
               runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Hyperlink control

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_hyperlink.asp